# What does "pulling out" mean?

Tags: sentence-construction

Does it mean to quit something -- such as a project?

Why not just say "quit" instead?

Does it have a precise meaning?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pull+out

Comment: Hello! Your question, as it is, can be readily answered by dictionaries and questions that can be answered by a quick dictionary lookup are [off-topic on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please try your dictionaries first and if the dictionaries can't help, you may edit this question to add more information telling us why the dictionaries can't help, along with your context and the exact sentence in your context. By the way, welcome to ELL!

Comment: @DamkerngT. - The O.P. has asked three questions here. In my mind, only the first of the three is "readily answerable by a dictionary." The second one is an interesting question, in my opinion, and not a very easy one to answer.

Comment: To the closevoters: This is a very hard phrase to interpret merely by consulting a dictionary. Put yourself in a learner's shoes, and [check this out](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pull%20out).

Comment: @J.R. I'm a learner, too. IMHO, asking *Why not just say "quit" instead?* is not a very good question, even though it's a fair question. It's not a very good question because it's not language specific. It's like asking why people say this or that or a specific thing in another language, or why someone said a word or a phrase on a specific occasion, why that someone didn't say something else, which from a learner's point of view, it could be the same (in some cases, the learner may think their choice is even better, or yet in some other cases, more correct). I simply addressed the obvious.

Comment: (cont.) *Does it have a precise meaning?* is similar. In other words, in my opinion, questions along the lines *Why not just say X (instead of Y)* and *Does X (a word or a phrase) have a precise meaning?* are more about how human languages work, not how a specific language (in our case, English) works. Then again, these questions could be more language specific and thus be more on-topic if the context was given and the way the word or the phrase is clear to everyone.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Actually, I think asking "Why not say —— instead?" can help suss out out subtleties of connotation and emphasis, which are hard to ask about if you don't already understand what's going on. This question in particular should get an answer explaining why in English "pulling out" is a natural metaphor for quitting, and how that metaphor suggests something more specific about the situation than just "quitting".

Comment: @DamkerngT. - None of those questions are all that deep on their own, but, if you examine all three questions together, I think they are pointing somewhere. That said, I realize your comment was intended to be helpful, and I did notice you didn't vote to close.

Comment: @BenK - There have been enough votes to reopen – go for it!

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the vote of confidence. When I wrote the comment above, though, I hadn't seen your excellent answer. Nice work! Maybe I'll try writing one myself, as a carrot for getting some work done…

Answer (score 2):

The two-word phrase *pull out* has several possible meanings. One of these meanings is similar to *quit*, but I think *pull out* has some implications that *quit* doesn't have. The two aren't exact synonyms; a closer synonym for *pull out of* might be *withdraw from*. One dictionary nicely defines pull out as:

> [**pull out**](http://onelook.com/?w=pull%20out&ls=a) (*phrasal verb*) remove oneself from an obligation

When something like a company "pulls out" of a project, it generally implies that there was some kind of support or investment made at one time, but the situation has changed, and the company will no longer provide that support, or continue that investment.

For example, here are some statements from recent news articles:

> ConocoPhillips, BP America and Caterpillar's announced Tuesday they will [**pull out**](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2010/02/16/major-firms-pull-climate-change-alliance.html) of the U.S. Climate Action Partnership, citing complaints that the bills now in Congress are unfair to American industry.
>
> Publishers Buzzfeed and Vox have said they will [**pull out**](http://smashd.co/gamergate/) of the 2016 SXSW event, if the panels are not reinstated.
>
> Saracens chairman Nigel Wray has vowed that English teams will be prepared to carry out their threat to [**pull out**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/rugbyunion/article-2414889/Saracens-insist-pull-Heineken-Cup-rules-dont-change.html) of the Heineken Cup.
>
> A number of other high-profile manufacturers have also confirmed they will [**pull out**](http://www.itproportal.com/2014/10/28/plasma-tv-industry-nearing-end-lg-winds-down-production) of the plasma TV business, with Panasonic announcing their exit in October.

In each of these news stories, some corporate entity is going to change their stance, either to make a political statement of some kind, or because the current course of action is no longer viable.

Put another way, a person might *quit* smoking, but a tobacco company might *pull out* of the cigarette business; a recording artist might *quit* touring, but a record company might *pull out of* a deal at the last minute.

That all said, there are times when the two words can be used almost interchangeably:

- The negotiators decided to *quit* the peace talks.
- The negotiators decided to *pull out of* the peace talks.

Answer (score 0):

It has different meanings depending of the given context.

***pull out*** (separable)

1. start moving (train)

   > *The train **pulls out** at noon.*
2. move into traffic

   > *It took me a while to **pull out** because of traffic congestion.*
3. withdraw

   > *The project didn't work so they decided to **pull out**.*
4. remove armed forces from an area

   > *People want the government to **pull** the soldiers **out**.*